# 5 band resistor. Red, orange, black, gold and black. It doesn't fit in to normal rules

Tags: resistors

[image]

I have a difficulty in identifying a five band resistor. Color sequence is red, orange, black, gold, and black. It doesn't fit in to normal rules.

Depending on the location of its use I expect that to be around 20 ohms. But I want to know if it is any how special as in low tolerance, or temperature etc.

Comment: How about a photo?

Comment: Well it comes out at 23 ohms for the first 4 bands on a 5 color band chart; check the last colour. https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-resistor-color-code-5-band

Comment: Added @Andyaka.

Comment: Image added @PeterSmith

Comment: The photo is not great. You should try to post a better image. Anyway, it looks damaged. Have you tried to measure it in circuit (with power off) using an ohmmeter?

Comment: R is damaged so no value with multimeter @LorenzoDonati

Answer (score 7):

That is likely a wire-wound power resistor with half the windings in the opposite direction so it is non-inductive.  That is what that final black band means.

[image]

Making it a 23Ω Non-inductive resistor.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new today! But, could you please provide a link or citation for the graphic that you used.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I am pretty sure I got that image from Yageo, but I am having a hard time finding a link to it now.  I see these a lot in low-value 2 W -  5 W power resistors.  You can often see the windings just under the ceramic coating going both ways.  I will keep looking for a reference and post what I find.

Comment: Nice find, but for a 5% resistor a 23 ohm value is weird. I'd bet that it is a 22 ohm resistor and the 2nd band color has been altered by heat and was originally red (the photo is not great and it seems the resistor is somewhat damaged).

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Good point...I don't think I've ever seen a 23Ω resistor!

Comment: Careful: last BLK band may also mean TemperatureCoefficient=250PPM